# Strip image metadata and rename it using a text file as source of input

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am ok with PowerShell or cmd-based suggestions. This is what I am trying to do:

I have this folder structure:

```
C:\Parent\Child01\ - Lots of JPG images
C:\Parent\Child02\ - Lots of JPG images
C:\Parent\Child03\ - Lots of JPG images
```

so on and so forth.

What I am doing currently manually:

1. I will be inside the Child 01 folder and run this command to strip meta data from all images

   `exif -r -all= -ext jpg -ext gif -ext png`
2. I have a txt file with keywords one per line. I want the images inside my current directory (Child01) to be replace with the names I gave in the text file.

How I am doing this right now is by using an excel sheet with 3 columns :

```
Original File Name  | New File Name | Rename Command
```

Original File Name has the content of all files names (I get this by running **`dir /b /a-d`**)
New File Name has my keywords
The Rename Command is a formula `=concatenate("ren ",A2,".jpg ",B2, ".jpg")`

This helps me generate the formula which I copy paste from command line to bulk rename.

Can some help me with a batch file or powershell script so I can get it all done in one go, please?

Comment: So there is no rhyme or reason as to what the new file name should be based on the original file name????  You just want to pull the first word from the text file and rename the first file in the directory to that.  Then rinse and repeat with the 2nd file and the 2nd word in the text file? What happens when there is more files in the directory then in your text file?

Comment: Yes you are correct. The for loop should exit when it runs out of images to rename. For example, the directory has 10 images and the text file has 12 lines. The script will use 1st 10 lines for renaming the first 10 images and it will exit. I do not have this problem manually because I know how many files I have in the folder and will copy only that many concatenated commands from the excel.

Comment: @BhavaniKannan, please remember to tag me when you are replying to me. You have not answered my last question in my previous comment.  **What happens when there is more files in the directory then in your text file?**  What should the script do when this happens?

Comment: @Squashman It will leave those extra files in the directory unnamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to bother Excel. It renames each .JPG to the next name of the file (it should just contain one column ("NewFileName" (without extension)). If it runs out of either files or lines, it stops.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
<file.txt (
  for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
    set "x="
    set /p x=
    if not defined x goto :eof
    ECHO ren "%%a" "!x!%%~xa"
  )
)
```

Check the output before you remove the `ECHO` command to actually enable the `ren` command.

Comment: Thank you @Stephan! Is there a way to incorporate ( exif -r -all= -ext jpg -ext gif -ext png ) command to strip the meta data via batch file too? If so can it be done before renaming the files please?

Comment: @BhavaniKannan what is stopping you from using that line of code as the first line of the batch file?

Comment: @squashman I used the command as second line after "echo off" and it said "No file specified"

Comment: @BhavaniKannan I'm not familiar with the `exif` tool, but I must admit that I already wondered why there is no filename or filemask given to tell it, what file(s) to process. Please check it's documentation.

Comment: I think I figured. I was missing a dot at the end of the command to indicate that the files are from current directory. It works now. Thank you!  exiftool -all:all= .